# Shell script: while read line mistake

Tags: shell

I have a shell script which read line from a file "input_file" with many lines, the frist several lines are as below:

```
04fcgFs-mjA
0DZ7DbdeOeE
0yvHWyvexZA
1IAhDGYlpqY
1Vajuce8nyU
1Y_wJR1I-9s
2dn-ULkQl5M
2GmVajkqLNU
2X85PdfQqnM
37LAPz7pnQI
```

In the script, I have:

```
while read line
do
blabla .....
done< input_file
```

It is very interesting that when the script reads the even lines, like the second, the fourth, the sixth, the first character will be missing. For example, when it reads the second line, the obtained string is `DZ7DbdeOeE`, not `0DZ7DbdeOeE`.

I tried to write a simple script with only:

```
while read line
do
echo $line
done< input_file
```

Then it can correctly reads `0DZ7DbdeOeE`.

Since my shell script is very long, I don't post it here but I think the inside codes have nothing to do with the "input_file". BTW, there are some blocks like

```
if [condition]
  continue
fi
```

So I JUST want to know what are the potential causes for this pheonomenum? It is so strange!

I have posted the script content in this link:
http://goo.gl/Iwory

Comment: I have my doubts. I suspect the problem is how you use `$line`.

Comment: What are you doing in `blabla .....`?

Comment: put the `echo "$line"` at the top of the loop in your big script, and see if it looks right there. Also, maybe you can use `read -r` (for raw) if your shell supports that option. Good luck.

Comment: Is the file from Windoze?  Could be there is a `\r` at the end of the line that is obscuring the character.  Use `dos2unix`

Comment: I put the echo "$line" at the top of the loop in my big script, and the result is as I said in the original post

Comment: ok, echo "$line" at top didn't help. Just to be sure, you're using exactly the same file for `input_file` in your big script VS your small-test script? Good luck.

Comment: yes, exatctly the same, besides, I noticed that the mistake not only happends on the second, but all the even lines, as updated in the original post

Comment: I have updated a link where the script content is pasted

Answer (score 0):

Something in your `blablabla` is reading from stdin, possibly to see if it's on a terminal or something like that.  Make sure that all external processes you run in there have their stdin redirected from `/dev/null`.

You can of course figure out what is doing it by commenting out sections of your `blablabla` and seeing when the behavior changes.